# Custom AllWindowFunction class members

Tags: java, apache-flink

I have a custom `AllWindowFunction` class which has a class member responsible for database inserts. The connection to the database is persistent and opens during construction.

The problem is, that the `AllWindowFunction` instance that creates/opens the connection isn't the same that gets called on apply event. Workaround for this is a static member, but I would like to know if that is the only workaround?

Example code:

```
public class CustomWindowFunction implements AllWindowFunction<String, String, TimeWindow> {

    private static Connection database;

    CustomWindowFunction() {
        database = new Connection();
    }

    @Override
    public void apply(TimeWindow timeWindow, Iterable<String> trades, Collector<String> out) {
        // process data
        database.save(data);
        out.collect(data.toString());
    }
}
```

I couldn't find anything regarding this mechanism, all I know is that object ID from constructor differs from object ID called from `apply`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the case because each function has to be serialized to be distributed across cluster's nodes. You can though try using `RichAllWindowFunction`, which is so called "Rich" version, where you have the `open()` method, which will be called in each parallel operator on its start.
In this method you could create the Connection

```
public class CustomWindowFunction implements RichAllWindowFunction<String, String, TimeWindow> {

    private Connection database;

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration parameters) {
        database = new Connection();
    }

    @Override
    public void apply(TimeWindow timeWindow, Iterable<String> trades, Collector<String> out) {
        // process data
        database.save(data);
        out.collect(data.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it works. How come "Rich" version supports "singleton" class members and "Normal" doesn't? Any example how to pass `Configuration` to the `open` method call?

Comment: It does not support "singleton" members. The contract is that the `open` will be called once by the framework in each parallel task.

Comment: So what makes the Connection instance the same when used in the `apply` function?

Comment: What do you understand as "singleton". Singleton usually means a pattern where instance of an object is created once per class and is shared across all instances of this class. In this sense the `Connection` is not a singleton.

Comment: Yeah, somehow wrong expression (that's why quoted were used). Well as explained in the problem, If I instantiate the `Connection` in `AllWindowFunction` constructor the `Connection` instance used in `apply` isn't the same. In case of `RichAllWindowFunction` using `open` method instance in `apply` is the same.